# How to get date in format 2022-03-17T08:06:20.411493824Z

Tags: date, date-utility

I can't seem to find any simple answers as to how to get the date `2022-03-17T08:06:20.411493824Z` with a simple bash command. The current date and time that is.

I tried the following, but I'm not getting the excess digits:

```
DATE=$(date '+%FT%TZ')

echo $DATE
```

Comment: On what operating system? The specifics will depend on what `date` implementation you are using.

Answer (score 5):

If you’re looking for the UTC time using ISO 8601 format, with nanoseconds, using GNU `date`:

```
date -Ins -u
```

If you’re after your exact format, still in UTC using GNU `date`:

```
date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ
```

or

```
date -u +%FT%T.%NZ
```

Comment: Ah so it was the `%N` that was tricking me!

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have access to GNU `date` (does it even make sense to get nanosecond precision when invoking `date` alone takes a few thousands if not millions of those), but if switching to other shells is an option, you can do:

In `zsh`:

```
TZ=UTC0 print -rP '%D{%FT%T.%9.Z}'
```

(here using prompt expansion via `print -P`)

Or:

```
zmodload zsh/datetime
TZ=UTC0 strftime %FT%T.%9.Z $epochtime
```

Or to store in a variable:

```
TZ=UTC0 print -rPv var '%D{%FT%T.%9.Z}'
```

Or:

```
zmodload zsh/datetime
TZ=UTC0 strftime -s var %FT%T.%9.Z $epochtime
```

Or:

```
() { local -x TZ=UTC0; var=${(%):-%D{%FT%T.%9.Z}}; }
```

With ksh93:

```
TZ=UTC0 printf '%(%FT%T.%NZ)T\n'
```

Or to store in a variable:

```
var=${ printf '%(%FT%T.%NZ)T'; }
```

`bash` did copy a subset of `ksh93`'s `printf '%(format)T' datespec` a few years back, but does not support `%N` for nanoseconds.

Since version 5.0, it added support for the `$EPOCHSECONDS` and `$EPOCHREALTIME` variables (not `$epochtime` array) from zsh. Only with microsecond precision, but may be enough for your use case:

```
t=$EPOCHREALTIME; TZ=UTC0 printf "%(%FT%T)T.${t#*.}Z\n" "${t%.*}"
```

All of those use only builtins and don't fork any process, so you should be able to run quite a few per millisecond.

```
$ repeat 10 TZ=UTC0 print -rP '%D{%FT%T.%9.Z}'
2022-03-17T12:04:56.563450377Z
2022-03-17T12:04:56.563488246Z
2022-03-17T12:04:56.563512375Z
2022-03-17T12:04:56.563530355Z
2022-03-17T12:04:56.563545833Z
2022-03-17T12:04:56.563559764Z
2022-03-17T12:04:56.563575171Z
2022-03-17T12:04:56.563594030Z
2022-03-17T12:04:56.563611980Z
2022-03-17T12:04:56.563626251Z
```

```
$ repeat 10 date -u +%FT%T.%NZ
2022-03-17T12:05:28.902806919Z
2022-03-17T12:05:28.905552036Z
2022-03-17T12:05:28.907594864Z
2022-03-17T12:05:28.908563238Z
2022-03-17T12:05:28.909433758Z
2022-03-17T12:05:28.910549552Z
2022-03-17T12:05:28.911642330Z
2022-03-17T12:05:28.912596098Z
2022-03-17T12:05:28.913575587Z
2022-03-17T12:05:28.914538184Z
```

Comment: After so many years wondering if eventually I could just "portably" print a basic time stamp without forking some tool, you come along ;). What makes me wonder, as well, is why Chet Ramey has not yet implemented `%N` precision in bash.

Comment: @ikaerom, see edit for bash 5.0+

Comment: Very cool! Thanks. It's going into my future scripts. Wouldn't `t=$EPOCHREALTIME; TZ=UTC0 printf "%(%FT%T)T.${t#*.}Z\n"` be sufficient? The second part `"${t%.*}"` is not needed anymore, right?

Comment: @ikaerom, with that `printf` would call `time()` again, so could give you the next second. For instance, `$EPOCHREALTIME` could expand to `1675456439.999996` and by the time `printf` is run, parses its arguments and calls `time()`, the current time will be a few dozens microsecond later, so the next second will have ticked and you'll get `2023-02-03T20:34:00.999996Z` on output instead of `2023-02-03T20:33:59.999996Z`

Comment: Thanks, mate. You're absolutely right. Haven't thought about this aspect. Sidenote: I remember you from back in the 90s on comp.unix.shell and other newsgroups. Together with Chris F.A. Johnson and Ted Timar, you consistently made the top-10 contributors list :). Clearly, this has not changed. What a pleasure!